# Multiplying two numbers in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using phpMyAdmin and I have two tables:

**___SalesTaxes**

```
|--------|----------|------------|
| STX_Id | STX_Name | STX_Amount |
|--------|----------|------------|
|      1 |    Tax 1 |       5.00 |
|      2 |    Tax 2 |      13.50 |
|--------|----------|------------|
```

**___BillableDatas**

```
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|--------------|----------|---------------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_BookingId | BIL_Date   | BIL_Status | BIL_Quantity | BIL_Rate | BIL_ApplicableTaxes |
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|--------------|----------|---------------------|
|      1 |             2 | 2018-03-06 | notcharged |           2  |   100.00 |                   1 |
|      2 |             2 | 2018-03-07 | notcharged |           3  |   105.00 |                 1,2 |
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|--------------|----------|---------------------|
```

---

I want to list per day a list of the billable things in `___BillableDatas` depending the status of the thing (charged vs notcharged).

So something like this:

```
|------------|-----------------|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|
|    Date    | BIL_Sum_Charged | BIL_Sum_Notcharged | Taxes_ForCharged | TaxesForNotCharged |
|------------|-----------------|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|
| 2018-03-06 |            0.00 |             200.00 |             0.00 |              10.00 |
| 2018-03-07 |            0.00 |             315.00 |             0.00 |             58.275 |
|------------|-----------------|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|
```

---

What I have actually:

```
SELECT b.BIL_Date,
SUM(case when b.BIL_Status = "charged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end
 / (1 + LENGTH(b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes, ",", "") ) ))
   as BIL_Sum_Charged, 
 SUM(case when b.BIL_Status = "notcharged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end
 / (1 + LENGTH(b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes, ",", "") )))
      as BIL_Sum_Notcharged,
  SUM(case when b.BIL_status = "charged" then s.STX_Amount else 0 end) 
      as STX_TAX_Charged,
  SUM(case when b.BIL_status = "notcharged" then s.STX_Amount else 0 end) 
     as STX_TAX_NotCharged
 FROM ___BillableDatas b
 INNER JOIN ___SalesTaxes s
 ON FIND_IN_SET(s.STX_id, b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes) > 0
 WHERE b.BIL_HotelId='cus_CNHLMiMOzP5cuM' 
 AND b.BIL_BookingId='2' 
 GROUP BY b.BIL_Date 
 ORDER BY b.BIL_Date ASC
```

---

Problem with this query is I do not have the right sum for `BIL_Sum_Charged` and `BIL_Sum_NotCharged` as the sum are not multiplying by the `BIL_Quantity` column.

For example, I've `105` whereas I should have `315` for `BIL_Sum_Notcharged` for 2018-03-07. Same for the taxes sums at the end.

Where is my error please ?

Please see the SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b3cb/1

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Why do you think you should have `315` and not `105`?

Comment: Because, from my datas, I should have the item `2` cost `105` and I've `BIL_Quantity` equal at `3`. 3*105=315. The report should sum/multiply the item cost by the quantity entered in `BIL_Quantity`.

Comment: `SUM(case when b.BIL_Status = "notcharged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end
 / (1 + LENGTH(b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes, ",", "") )))` You are adding it twice for two rows in that date and then dividing it by 2. Where is the `*3`?

Comment: This is what I do not know how to make it. My actual query looks working except for the multiplication.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6365f/6

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes it looks. Do you know how I can make the same for the taxes ?

Comment: Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

After discussing, this seems to be what you need. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT b.BIL_Date,
SUM(case when b.BIL_Status = "charged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end
 / (1 + LENGTH(b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes, ",", "") ) )) * b.BIL_Quantity
   as BIL_Sum_Charged, 
 SUM(case when b.BIL_Status = "notcharged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end
 / (1 + LENGTH(b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes, ",", "") ))) * b.BIL_Quantity
      as BIL_Sum_Notcharged,
  SUM(case when b.BIL_status = "charged" then s.STX_Amount else 0 end) * (SUM(case when b.BIL_Status = "charged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end
 / (1 + LENGTH(b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes, ",", "") ) )) * b.BIL_Quantity) / 100
      as STX_TAX_Charged,
  SUM(case when b.BIL_status = "notcharged" then s.STX_Amount else 0 end) * ( SUM(case when b.BIL_Status = "notcharged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end
 / (1 + LENGTH(b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes, ",", "") ))) * b.BIL_Quantity) / 100
     as STX_TAX_NotCharged
 FROM ___BillableDatas b
 INNER JOIN ___SalesTaxes s
 ON FIND_IN_SET(s.STX_id, b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes) > 0
 WHERE b.BIL_HotelId='cus_CNHLMiMOzP5cuM' 
 AND b.BIL_BookingId='2' 
 GROUP BY b.BIL_Date 
 ORDER BY b.BIL_Date ASC;
```

**Edited** based on discussion.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The taxes sum are wrong. For 2018-03-07, I should have `58.27` and not `55.5` Because the sum of the 2 taxes are `18.5`. `18.5% of 315 = 58.27`.

Comment: 13.5+5 = 18.5 * 3 = 55.5 How are you getting 58.27?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. My taxe rates are `5%` and `13.5%`. It's percentage, not sum. So `5% + 13.5% = 18.5%` and `18.5% of 315 = 58.27`. Let me know if it's unclear. Thanks.

Comment: It is clear now. That's not what you are doing in the query. Lemme fix it.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Wow! That was fast. Thanks so much for your kind help!

Comment: Sorry to cam back again but I have an error with your query. If for the same day, I have two items and those items don't have the same taxe amount, your actual query will sum them and not make the calculation separately. You can check my example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5d926/1. For the `2018-03-06` I get `64.68` whereas I should get `17.13` because the taxes are the same for the two items for this date. I don't know if you can help me again with that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should ask another question. Give details like what data you have and what is the expected output. The expected output should not just have the numbers you expect but also how you calculate them for each column. Giving information one column at a time is not the best way to do this.